# Facebook like button redirection?

Tags: facebook, redirect

I tried to install Facebook Like Button (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/) on my page but after I've put the code (HTML5 version) there is some strange redirect which change address of the page adding "`_FB_f2af6423b6fd064xd_action=proxy_ready&data`" to it?

Do you have any idea what may cause the problem?

I can install iframe version of like box but some time ago I received an information about similar problem while there was some toolbar installed in the web browser. String in url was different but result the same - error 404.

You can see the problem here: www.keeeper.voyagersblog.com/en/ and properly working page (without like button) here: www.bea.trvblog.com/en/ .

Thank you for help!

Best regards, 
Bartek

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I have my own js EventListener called 'message' and it seems that facebook use the same name.
My event listener is fired by fb script and then my function makes redirect (params are not proper so it goes nowewhere).
When I changed listener name it's ok, it seems that it's fb bug.
Thank you anyway!